# Can I force a BLOB to be stored externally in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have a table which, for historic reasons contains some HTML and PDF contents. It also contains a filenames/URLs in the case that the HTML and PDF contents have been written to storage.

Currently the application will write the PDF and HTML to the table, then another process reads those, writes them to disk and puts `NULL` into the HTML and PDF contents fields.

My database is getting very large and costing more than I had anticipated and I'm wondering if this storage is not being freed correctly. I have two questions:

1. Can I validate this theory? Currently I'm looking at `information_schema.TABLES.DATA_LENGTH` and `INDEX_LENGTH` to see the space being used by the table but I'm not sure I've fully understood these and the `DATA_FREE` value.
2. If it is the writing of these medium/small BLOBs that's causing the problem, can I force them into external storage on the basis that I know they will be set to `NULL` later?

Comment: If you don't want your application to store BLOBs in the database, why don't you change it?

Comment: I am doing so but that takes time.

Comment: Just for clarity, by "external" I mean separately from the rest of the record as described here https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/externally-stored-fields-in-innodb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  MySQL has no control over BLOB location, but your workaround is sound.

Long answer:

No, although InnoDB *does* put big `BLOBs` in a different place, you have no control over this "off-record" storage mechanism. And you must continue to use `INSERT`, `SELECT`, etc to access them.

The problem is that an InnoDB tablespace only increases in size; it never shrinks except by `OPTIMIZE TABLE` (or specific equivalent actions).

As already mentioned, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` will give space back to the OS, *if* the table had been created with `innodb_file_per_table = ON`.  But it *may* a long time.  I say "may" because it only needs to copy what is left, plus a few bytes for those NULLs you left behind.  Hence, it *may* not take too long after *all* the blobs have been moved out.

In general, (as you have surmised) it is better to throw pdfs and htmls on disk and let other htmls fetch them via `<img src=...>` or similar things.

And, yes, the "elsewhere" could easily be some other (cheaper?) server; `<img>` does not care which machine it is reaching into.

Answer (score -1):

**Reducing Storage** csn be done by using the optimize command. The database generally wint decrease storage space on the fly because it will an adverse impsct on speed on a live system

> The MySQL OPTIMIZE table helps you to optimize the table storage space. It reorganizes the storage data in a way that increases the Input Output efficiency and reduces the storage space. To execute this statement, you need SELECT and INSERT privileges. Following is the syntax of the MySQL OPTIMIZE TABLE Statement −

From [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql_optimize_table_statement.htm)

**Storing blobs to database** is done by your application. Its a choice made by rhe developer. You can change your program to store them to separate files

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what I mean by "stored externally" - I mean the feature of MySQL where it will store a BLOB outside of the normal table storage but inside the database.

Comment: Like the "off-record" that I mentioned.  In contrast, MyISAM stores the blog with the rest of the columns.